# list.remove(x): x not in list on a random number list

Tags: python, random

I am getting `list.remove(x)` error
So what am I doing here is that, am using this program to generate random numbers without duplicates from a set range and removing the number as the number has been called but somehow I am getting not in the list message even though the random has been called from the list.

```
import random
def checkPizza(numOfPizza):
    pizzaD = []
    allowed_val = list(range(0,M+1))
    if numOfPizza == 2:
        allowed_val = allowed_val
        while True:
            allowed_val = allowed_val
            alpha = random.choice(allowed_val)
            beta = random.choice(allowed_val)
            if alpha != beta:
                allowed_val.remove(alpha)
                allowed_val.remove(beta)
                pizzaD.append(alpha)
                pizzaD.append(beta)
                break
```

Comment: Illustrate what is your requirement clearly step by step or by using an example of input of output from what you have mentioned it is very much unclear. I do not see what you want to achieve in this code of yours, also assigning the same variable multiple times to itself makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me. You did not define M here so I chose an arbitrary number:

```
import random
def checkPizza(numOfPizza):
    pizzaD = []
    allowed_val = list(range(0,10))
    if numOfPizza == 2:
        allowed_val = allowed_val
        while True:
            allowed_val = allowed_val
            alpha = random.choice(allowed_val)
            beta = random.choice(allowed_val)

            if alpha != beta:
                allowed_val.remove(alpha)
                allowed_val.remove(beta)
                pizzaD.append(alpha)
                pizzaD.append(beta)
                print(pizzaD)
                break


checkPizza(2)
```

output:

```
[7, 5]
```

It is howevery not clear for me what `allowed_val=allowed_val` is suppose to do.
It appears twice in your code.
Also I think you are using a while loop for the case that alpha equals beta.
In my opinion the following would be prefered:

```
alpha,beta = random.sample(allowed_val,2)
```

This will asign two values from the list of allowed_val that are not the same.
In this case you do not need the `while True` loop